# batch script to display file names in a directory older than 30 days?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set dir_path="<path>"

rem *********set min age of files and folders to be  displayed**********
set max_days= 30

rem *********display FILE names from %dir_path%*********

dir %dir_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% /-p /o:gn > "C:\Users\Desktop\DirContents.txt"

exit


**************************************************************************************************
```

Here from the above script I am able to display the entire list of files and folders in a particular directory. But not files or folders older than 30 days. Please help

Comment: Thanks for all your support..

Answer (score 3):

```
forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c echo @path is older than 30 days."
```

Answer (score 1):

`robocopy %dir_path% %dir_path% /L /V /MINAGE:30 /NJH /NJS /LOG:C:\Users\Desktop\DirContents.txt`

This will run robocopy only on %dir_path%.

```
/L only outputs the output of the command but doesn't move anything
/V enables verbose mode, which allows the filenames to be printed
/MINAGE:30 only returns files and folders older than 30 days
/NJH prevents the job header from being printed
/NJS prevents the job summary from being printed
/LOG:C:\Users\Desktop\DirContents.txt outputs the result to a text file
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way using jscript/bat hybrid (should be saved as .bat) :

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* jscript comment

@echo off
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
exit /b
******************    end comment  */

var objFSO  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

//var objStartFolder = "C:\Scripts";


var curr_ms = (new Date()).getTime();
var _30days_to_ms=1000*60*60*24*30;

ShowSubFolders(".");

function ShowSubFolders (folder) {
    var objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folder);
    var colFiles = objFolder.Files;
    var colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders;

    for(var objEnum = new Enumerator(colFiles); !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext()) {
       strFileName = objEnum.item();

       var fileDate_ms =(new Date(strFileName.DateCreated)).getTime();
       if (curr_ms - fileDate_ms > _30days_to_ms ) {
         WScript.Echo(strFileName);
       }


    }

    for(var objEnum = new Enumerator(colFolders); !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext()) {
        ShowSubFolders(objEnum.item());
    }
}
```

with this you can filter files with more detailed measurements like seconds, minutes,weeks...